Printer redirection Google Cloud Windows Server 2022 virtual machine Canon GX7000 problem
I am using IAP Desktop to connect to a windows server 2022 vm in google cloud. I am trying to print to a Canon GX7000 which is hooked directly up to the local machine and prints successfully from the local machine. I have print redirection enabled and can successfully redirect printing to the local pdf printer. I expected it to redirect without installing drivers on the vm, but since it doesn't, I have the most recent driver for the canon gx7000 downloaded to the vm, however it will not install because of the error "the program is not supported by the operating system" I have shared the printer on the local machine, checked firewall settings, enabled Redirect Devices, Drives, and Ports in the IAP Desktop interface. What else can I do to try and resolve this.
I tried enabling Redirect printers. I expected it to print to the Canon GX7000, which is set to default on the local machine. I tried installing the printer driver on the vm. I expected the driver to install but got an error "the program is not supported by the operating system". I tried sharing the printer on the local machine and expected it to be available on the vm. I tried printing a test page from the local machine which worked successfully. I tried printing to the local pdf printer which worked successfully.

Printers are part of Network Sharing. That means the VM must be able to directly access your computer over the Internet. That can be a challenge unless you have static public IP addresses and understand networking. However, I do not recommend ever doing that for security reasons. I get around some of those problems by using WireGuard to create a virtual network between my machine and the VM. However, the printer driver issue is not related to any of that. You must install a driver compatible with your OS. Break your problem into multiple posts, otherwise, you limit who can help you.

The error "the program is not supported by the operating system" means that the printer driver that you are using is not compatible with your OS. Printer drivers must also match the operating system's architecture. If the OS of your VM is using a 32-bit version, you must use a 32-bit printer driver and if the OS of your VM is using a 64-bit version, you must use a 64-bit version of printer driver. Visit the manufacturer website of your printer and look for the driver specifically designed for the system type of your VM's operating system.
